# Firebase functions update stripe user

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-functions, stripe-connect

How can I properly update an existing stripe account
here's what I tried I don't think I'm doing it right, I keep getting this error message from firebase Functions log:

> ReferenceError: request is not defined at admin.database.ref.once.then.then.customer

```
exports.updateStripeUser = functions.database.ref('/users/{userId}').onWrite(event => {
         const val = event.data.val
        if (val === null || val.id || val.error) return null;
      // Look up the Stripe customer id written in createStripeAccount
      return 
      admin.database().ref(`/users/${event.params.userId}/customer_id`).once('value').then(snapshot => {
        return snapshot.val();
      }).then(customer => { 

      return stripe.accounts.update({
           {customer},
           {
             tos_acceptance: {
               date: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) ,
               ip: request.connection.remoteAddress // Assumes you're not using a proxy
               }
            }
         });
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to trigger via HTTP request in order to get the connection IP address. Use express and add a `POST` request for your client to post to, then retrieve the address from the `req`.

```
const app = require('express')();

app.post("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.get('X-Forwarded-For') || req.connection.remoteAddress);
});

exports.tos_acceptance = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

You can trigger this from your client and it will return a public IP address. You will need to update your stripe user with this address. You can retrieve it on the client and write it to your user in the real-time database as part of your `onWrite` trigger.

Though, another way would involve posting from the client with the current user's ID token as the `Authorization` header of the request. You can decode the header on the server to get the corresponding user's ID – with which you can assume authorization to update the user's stripe.

```
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true });
const app = require('express')();

app.use(cors);
app.post("/", (req, res) => {
    const idToken = `${req.get('Authorization')}`.split('Bearer ')[1];
    const ipAddress = req.get('X-Forwarded-For') || req.connection.remoteAddress;

    if (!idToken) return res.send(401);
    if (!ipAddress) return res.send(403);

    return admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken).then(uid => {
        // update stripe user
    }).catch(error => {
        res.status(500).send(error);
    });
});

exports.tos_acceptance = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to assume there is a `request` variable that allows it to determine the IP address of the  user. This sounds like the code was written for running inside a web server, such as Express.js.

But since you're triggering this Cloud Functions through a write to the database, there is no request that you can read the IP address from. If this information is needed to call `stripe.accounts.update(...)`, then you should write it to the database and read it from there through `event.data.val()`.

Comment: Ahh Thank you, I'm having trouble retrieving the customer_ id from firebase. Th update function is still not working. How would you suggest I do it?